# Disk leak on Ubuntu with Hadoop and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, memory-leaks

I'm using Hadoop with Eclipse in Ubuntu 12 VirtualBox Guest with Windows 8 Host for development of MapReduce programs. I'm using a large data during unit testing and apparently there are some memory leaks as the hadoop program throws disk error after few trials. I closed the eclipse, but memory still doesn't show back in my Windows Task Manager. After I restart the Ubuntu machine, I am able to run the programs again till there is a disk error. Did any one faced similar issue or know how to fix this ?

Comment: Before assuming there's a bug in Eclipse, Hadoop, JRE or Ubuntu, better check your code for leaks. 90% of the cases it's your code that's wrong.

Comment: @m0skit0, I closed my program, exit eclipse and closed everything. Still my code can leave bad things ? Since this is a java program, all memory should be cleared by gc after my program is killed ?

Comment: Why a -1 for this ? It can be a cache issue also ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be freed, but if you spawn some server or separate process, it might be still running in a separate JVM. You can check all running Java processes using `ps -A | grep java`. I didn't downvote, but for me this question is actually off-topic.

Comment: @m0skit0, thanks for that. May be I should have put the question in a different way. I din't mean to say there is an issue with all the software I mentioned but just said something bad is happening when I used all of them. I tried freeing cache, but it still the memory is same in task manager. May be I did not free the cache right way. Thanks for your inputs. I will grep for java and check again.

Comment: I use Eclipse in Ubuntu and never had this problem. I highly doubt VB can have anything to do with it too, since I've been using it too and never heard of such a problem.

Comment: @m0skit0, do you also run Hadoop programs in Eclipse by chance ?

Comment: There is a lot of Hadoop data stored in my tmp folder. I cleared the tmp folder and now it shows me disk space. I was thinking that is something with memory. But I suspect something similar with memory as well.

Comment: Memory leak != disk leak

Comment: @JudgeMental sorry for that. I think I should rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran with large data, the program in eclipse ended with Disk space error and did not clear the tmp folder. I manually deleted the hadoop files in tmp folder and I saw the disk space back again. Dropping caches did not help in this case.